# How to add css styling to a input field label in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component from semantic-ui Form as shown below:

When the input field reaches certain length it will change label to a different wording.

How do I add css styling to the wording? for example make it bold and red?

thanks.

```
<Form.Input
            name='Filename'
            label={this.state.fileLabel}
            value={this.props.data.value}
            onChange={checkFileNameLength}
            
        />
```

Comment: @Does this solves your problem https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming/

Comment: Hi what do you mean by the change of width of input are you saying for the mobile devices or when the user enters input in input field then you are talking about that.Please clarify so we can help you.

Comment: @ProgrammingHobby, I'm mean when user entered certain number of characters in the input field. Basically, when that happens I want to change the label to a different colour - like red and bold.

Comment: ok i'm posting the answer after some time its easy